# Can I use $in within mongodb's $match aggregate function

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation

I am trying to use the $in operator within the $match (aggregate) function. For some reason its not working on the '_Id' field but I can't find any documentation noting that this is not supported in mongodb.

```
var ids = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];  //an example. I am using real mongo object ids


// this is working fine
Product.find({_id : {$in : ids}})
 .exec(function(err, res){
  res.json(res);
  });

// no results here
Product.aggregate([
 {$match : {_id : {$in : ids}}},
 {$group : {_id : '$pCode', total : {$sum : '$pWeight'}}])
  .exec(function(err, res){
   res.json(res);
```

Now if I use other fields to query it works fine and I get the desired result using $in. But for some reason this is not working for the '_id' field.

Comment: Mongoose won't do any casting of `ids` for you with `aggregate`, but it will for `find`. So make sure `ids` contains actual `ObjectId` objects, and not just strings.

Comment: I will suggest, make mongoose debug true so that u can debug easily.

Comment: Thanks JohnnyHK. Once I have proper Object IDs every was working as expected.  I wish the mongodb documentation would mention that. clearly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try using

```
const ObjectId = require("mongodb").ObjectID;
```

and then convert your array like this :

```
var ids = [ObjectId('5ae6d812e5504726a69fc285'),ObjectId('5b0bcfc254c93a2734d56efb')];
```

and then do your aggregation.
For aggregation using ORM, you have to cast it explicitly.

Comment: Ankit - thank you very much for the answer. That was the problem. I wish the mongodb documentation would make it easier to find these restrictions.

Answer (score 3):

`$in` operator works just fine with `$match`.

Your aggregate seems to not be correct after the match however:

```
Product.aggregate([
 {$match : {_id : {$in : ids}}},
 {$group : {_id : '$pCode', total : {$sum : '$pWeight'}}}
]).exec(function(err, res){
   res.json(res);
})
```

See if this would work if not simply run the query without the group so you can see that it works and then work on your `$group` part.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I corrected the syntax but this not address the problem.