# Get students for given list of classes in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

As specified below, I have section and class schema in my MongoDB.

How can I query all the students of a given list of Class IDs?

```
const sectionsSchema = new Schema({
    section: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    students:[{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }]
})


const classSchema = new Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    institution: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Institution'
    },
    divisions :[{
        type: sectionsSchema,
        required: true
    }]
    
},{timestamps: true})
```

Below is the Example Data

Class: [{
_id: 'Class1',
institution: 'inst1',
divisions:[{
section: 'A',
students: ['Stud1','Stud2']
},
{
section: 'B',
students: ['Stud3','Stud4']
}]
},
{
_id: 'Class2',
institution: 'inst1',
divisions:[{
section: 'A',
students: ['Stud5','Stud6']
}]
}]

```
    input: ['Class1','Class2'];
    Expected Output: ['Stud1','Stud2','Stud3','Stud4','Stud5','Stud6'];
```

Comment: Can you add example that what should be output on your specific input?

Comment: Hi @DrashtiKheni,
I have added the example code if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to use an aggregate query as following:

```
.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: {
        $in: [
          "Class1",
          "Class2"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$divisions"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$divisions.students"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$divisions"
    }
  },
])
```

Example output:

```
[
  {
    "section": "A",
    "students": "Stud1"
  },
  {
    "section": "A",
    "students": "Stud2"
  },
  {
    "section": "B",
    "students": "Stud3"
  },
  {
    "section": "B",
    "students": "Stud4"
  },
  {
    "section": "A",
    "students": "Stud5"
  },
  {
    "section": "A",
    "students": "Stud6"
  }
]
```

You afterwards have to map the documents returned to simple strings, since mongoose is not able to return plain strings.

Comment: Hi Fabjan,

Thanks for the solution. On removing '$match' block, I'm getting the result for all the Classes in DB. But with '$match', the result is empty. Any idea!!

Comment: I assume your sample data was not according to your actual schema. I guess you want to match on given names and not the actual IDs. Maybe you can try to exchange "_id" for "name" in your $match query.

Comment: Its working now Fabjan, thanks for the solution.

This is kind of weird. With 'aggregation', _id in the form of string is not working. It has to be converted into Object Id: 

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52196445/can-i-use-in-within-mongodbs-match-aggregate-function

Comment: Yeah, I stumble across this issue once in a while. I also think this is kind of a strange behaviour, but glad that it worked out for you!